# Option for FILTER ISNA MATCH but for sensitive case and can be used on columns with different total rows

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

[To access the Google Sheets for tests click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BHjFAxEI5avHTQ3aSXiSVUGWzsEAao1Dmsh0E1Hp8xM/edit?usp=sharing)

Column `A` in Page `Registered` → total 10 rows:

```
Arsenal de Sarandi
Palmeiras
Vasco
Flamengo
Goiás
Barcelona B
Almeria
```

Columns `A,B` in Page News using `=FILTER(A1:A,ISNA(MATCH(A1:A,Registered!A1:A,0)))` in `B1`. total 6 rows:

```
Arsenal De Sarandi           Barcelona
Palmeiras
Vasco
Flamengo
Goiás
Barcelona
```

Expected Result in Page News:

```
Arsenal De Sarandi           Arsenal De Sarandi
Palmeiras                    Barcelona
Vasco
Flamengo
Goiás
Barcelona
```

I tried:

```
=FILTER(A1:A,REGEXMATCH(Registered!A1:A,A1:A)=FALSE)
```

Error:

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected Row Count: 6, Expected
> Column Count: 1. Actual Row Count: 10, Actual Column Count: 1.

But when it has the same amount of rows, it's still wrong because it finds `Barcelona` in `Barcelona B`, so the column of values only returns `Arsenal De Sarandi`.

So I tried:

```
=FILTER(A1:A,EXACT(Registered!A1:A,A1:A)=FALSE)
```

Error:

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected Row Count: 6, Expected
> Column Count: 1. Actual Row Count: 10, Actual Column Count: 1.

How to perfectly convert the `FILTER ISNA MATCH` to case sensitive without worrying about different sizes of total lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A1:A, REGEXMATCH(A1:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Registered!A1:A))=FALSE)
```

Comment: @DigitalFarmer answer updated