# Filter names with spaces and special characters from a column that are not in another column using case sensitive

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

[Google Sheets for tests](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CiMOQeANhX0WwzDf9JMAIonuzgZ3LFjTr0OTJ3bMdrk/edit?usp=sharing)

To use in lists for sensitive cases, [this indicated option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72766152/11462274) works perfectly:

```
=FILTER(D1:D, REGEXMATCH(D1:D, "\b"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A1:A)&"\b")=FALSE)
```

But for my columns that have names the filter result does not return correctly as it should

List of saved values:

```
Vancouver Whitecaps
Montreal Impact
Toronto FC
Everton De Vina
12 de Octubre de Itaugua
Al Ahly Cairo
Aldosivi
Argentinos Juniors
Atletico Go
Atletico MG
Atletico Nacional Medellin
Athletico-PR
Atl Tucuman
Audax Italiano
Bahia
Barnechea
Beijing Guoan
Ceara SC Fortaleza
Central Cordoba (SdE)
Cerro Porteno
Chaco For Ever
Changchun Yatai
Chapecoense
Guarani (Par)
Nacional (Par)
Colo Colo
Colon
Corinthians
CRB
Criciuma
Cruzeiro MG
CSA
Daegu FC
Dalian Yifang
La Serena
Deportes Temuco
Tolima
Eastern Company SC
Estudiantes
FC Seoul
Flamengo
Fluminense
Fortaleza EC
Gangwon
General Caballero
Ghazl El Mahallah
Gimnasia La Plata
Goias
Gremio
Guairena
Guangzhou City
Guarani
Henan
Incheon Utd
CA Independiente
Independiente Cauquenes
Jeju Utd
Jeonbuk Motors
Libertad
Londrina
National Bank
Newells
Olimpia
Operario PR
SE Palmeiras
Patronato
CA Platense
Pohang Steelers
Ponte Preta
Provincial Ovalle FC
Pyramids
Racing Club
Resistencia SC
Rosario Central
Sampaio Correa FC
CSD San Antonio Unido
San Lorenzo
Gimcheon Sangmu
Santos
Sao Paulo
Seongnam FC
Shandong Luneng
Shenzhen FC
Shijiazhuang Yongchang FC
Sol de America (Par)
Club Sportivo Ameliano
Suwon Bluewings
Suwon FC
Tacuary
Talleres
Tianjin Teda
Univ Catolica (Chile)
Ulsan Hyundai Horang-i
Vasco Da Gama
Velez Sarsfield
Wuhan Zall
Zamalek
Zhejiang Greentown
Fernandez Vial
CD General Velasquez
Cobreloa Calama
Puerto Montt
Viking
Univ de Concepcion
Santiago Morning
Magallanes
Junior FC Barranquill
Gimnasia Jujuy
Meizhou Hakka
Independiente Rivadavia
Agropecuario
Ferro Carril Oeste
Turkey
Wuhan Three Towns
Hebei CFFC
Martinique
Grenada
Suriname
Chengdu Better City FC
Curacao
Los Andes
Schaffhausen
CSD Liniers de Ciudad Evita
Belgrano
Club Petrolero
Deportivo Madryn
Botafogo

Tristan Suarez
Sol De Mayo
Deportivo Moron
Perth Glory

Union Santa Fe

Flandria
CA Colegiales
Atletico San Luis
United City F.C.
Brown de Adrogue
Caracas
San Martin de Tucuman
Ismaily
Hoang Anh Gia Lai
Mafra
Smouha




Ham-Kam
Orlando Pirates (SA)
Varnamo
Chiangrai Utd
Future FC
El Gounah
Home Utd
Jeonnam Dragons
Johor Darul Takzim
Al Mokawloon

Helsingborgs
Jerv
Sundsvall
Mazatlan FC
Gaziantep FK
Cruz Azul
Misr El Makasa
Al Wehdat
Al-Shabab (KSA)
Al Faisaly ( KSA )
Al-Sadd
Al Rayyan
Al Quwa Al Jawiya
Sepahan
Foolad
Al Ahli (UAE)
Ahal FC
Al Gharafa
Al-Duhail SC
Emelec
Alianza Lima
Independiente (Ecu)
Always Ready
Al Ittihad (EGY)
Argeș Pitești
Roda JC
Vietnam
Lebanon
South Korea
Iraq
China
Ghana
Australia

Nigeria
Poland
Morocco

Union San Felipe
Real San Joaquin
Deportes Recoleta
Rodelindo Roman FC
Mali
Algeria

JS Saoura
Etoile Sportive Sahel
Belouizdad
URT
Horoya AC
Pharco FC
El Geish
Ceramica Cleopatra
Al-Taawoun Buraidah
Estudiantes de Merida
Royal Pari
Nasaf
Al Jaish
Al Zawraa
IFK Goteborg
Norrkoping
AS Otoho
Al-Ittihad Tripoli
Caldense Mg
Wydad Casablanca
Guabira
Delfin
Cerro Largo FC
Club Nueve de Octubre
Wanderers (Uru)
The Strongest
Ayacucho Futbol Club
Mushuc Runa
CD Hermanos Colmenarez
Sport Boys (Per)
Melgar
Cienciano
Oriente Petrolero
Jong Ajax Amsterdam
Jong PSV Eindhoven
Jong FC Utrecht
Jong AZ Alkmaar
ASEC Mimosas
Charlotte FC
Defensa y Justicia
Universitario de Deportes
Univ Catolica (Ecu)
Monagas
Zanaco FC
Al-Masry
Al Ahli Tripoli
Royal Leopards
Democrata GV
Sportive de Tunis
Kyoto
Iwata
Al Merreikh
Comunicaciones
CD Motagua
Guastatoya
Forge
Deportivo Saprissa
Santos de Guapiles
USGN
TP Mazembe
Coton S De Garoua
Simba
Club Sportif Sfaxien
Jwaneng Galaxy FC
ES Setif
Petro Luanda
Amazulu
Caen
Al Hilal Omdurman
G.D. Sagrada Esperanca
Barracas Central
Central Coast Mariners
Universidad Cesar Vallejo
Tombense MG
Bolivar
Torque
Melbourne Victory
Rangers U19
Al Jazira
Wellington Phoenix
Sydney FC
Newcastle Jets
Brisbane Roar
Egypt
Senegal
Macarthur FC
Athletic Club
Pouso Alegre
Santo Andre
Western Sydney Wanderers
Melbourne City
Cameroon
Tunisia
Sao Bernardo
Botafogo SP
Agua Santa
Mirassol
CA Patrocinense
Union Magdalena
Inter Limeira
Ituano
Villa Nova MG
Cortulua
Ferroviaria
Novorizontino
Bastia
Portsmouth
CF Rayo Majadahonda
Atletico Mancha Real
Linares Deportivo
Alcoyano
Charlton
Mardin BB
Bodrum Belediyesi Bodr
Arenteiro
Talavera CF
Atletico Baleares
U.D Llanera
Albacete
Deportivo
Bergantinos CF
Leonesa
Union de Salamanca
Zamora
CD Castellon
Atletico Sanluqueno CF
Malmo U19
Tigres
Kidderminster
Yeovil
Buxton
Gateshead
CD Puertollano
CD Utrillas
CA Pulpileno
Velez CF
San Agustin Guadalix
Guijuelo
SD Gernika Club
Pena Sport
Leioa
AD Union Adarve
Xerez
CD Ibiza Islas Pitiusas
Nazilli Belediyespor
Van Buyuksehir Belediyespor


CE Andratx
CD Mensajero
SD Solares
Cordoba
Gimnastica Segoviana CF
CD Brea
UD Alzira
UCAM Murcia
CE Europa
Cacereno
Alicante
CF Panaderia Pulido
San Roque Lepe
76 Igdir Belediyespor
CD Cayon
CD Marchamalo
Victoria CF

Unami CP
CD Teruel
Union Club Ceares
Racing Rioja CF
CFJ Mollerusa
CD Ebro
UD Montijo
Aguilas
CD Badajoz
Racing de Ferrol
Manisa FK
SV Turkgucu-Ataspor
Wurzburger Kickers
FK Crvena Zvezda U19
Orebro
Santos Laguna
Wolves U21
Liverpool U21
Southampton U21
Leicester U21
Newcastle U21
Dag and Red
St Albans
Greuther Furth
Stratford Town
Notts Co
Stockport
Maidenhead
Southend
Eastleigh
Hayes & Yeading
Kings Lynn
Banbury Utd
Horsham FC
Bromley
Harrow Borough FC
Solihull Moors
Guiseley
Wrexham
Havant and W
Ebbsfleet Utd
Bowers & Pitsea
Apollon Smirnis
Duisburg
Saarbrucken
1860 Munich
AFC Sudbury
Nurnberg
Mgladbach
RB Leipzig U19
Deportivo La Coruna U19
Genk U19
FC Minsk U19
Empoli U19
FC Kairat Almaty U19
Az Alkmaar U19
FC Midtjylland U19
Trabzonspor U19
Villarreal
Everton U21
Leeds United U21
Brighton U21
Arsenal U21
Cambuur Leeuwarden
Oleksandria
Genclerbirligi
Kahramanmarasspor
68 Aksaray Belediyespor
Tepecik Belediye
Karakopru Belediyespor
Pendikspor
Diyarbekirspor
Nigde Belediyespor
Ajax Amateurs
Kirklarelispor
Yeni Orduspor
Bayburt Sport

Arnavutkoy Belediyesi GVS
Duzcespor
Pazarspor
Kahta 02 Spor
Agri 1970 Spor
Darica Genclerbirligi
Yomraspor
Sanliurfaspor
Edirnespor
Fatsa Belediyespor
Sivas Belediyespor
Ergene Velimese SK
Nevsehir Belediyespor

Inegolspor
Karsiyaka
Kestel Spor
Cankaya
Excelsior Maassluis
DOVO
BVV Barendrecht
Rijnsburgse Boys
Unitas Gorinchem
VV Gemert
SV Oss 20
VV Capelle
Ijsselmeervogels
AFC Amsterdam
GVVV
Sile Yildizspor
Ceyhanspor
Artvin Hopaspor
Excelsior
Almere City
FC Oss
Helmond Sport
VVV Venlo
SC Telstar
ADO Den Haag
MVV Maastricht
FC Dordrecht
FC Eindhoven
SteDoCo FC
Kozakken Boys
Sparta Nijkerk
ACV Assen
ASWH
Spakenburg
SV DVS 33 Ermelo
Emmen
De Graafschap
Crystal Palace U21
Adiyamanspor
Somaspor Spor Kulubu
Eyupspor
Akhisar Belediye
Carsambaspor
Konyaspor
Amed Sportif Faaliyetler
Belediye Derincespor
Man City U21
West Ham U21
Aston Villa U21
Chelsea U21
Tottenham U21
Hammarby
Malmo FF
Kalmar FF
LR Vicenza Virtus
Ascoli
Antwerp
Aris
Fortuna Dusseldorf
Halmstads
San Telmo
Sutton Utd
Georgia
Luxembourg
Bulgaria
Ukraine
Czech Republic
Jamaica
Costa Rica
Canada
Panama
Burton Albion
Harrogate Town
Hartlepool
Salford City
Port Vale
Mansfield
Crawley Town
Scunthorpe
Exeter
Fleetwood Town
Sheff Wed
Lincoln
MK Dons
WSG Wattens
Godoy Cruz
CA Temperley
Alashkert
Zenit St Petersburg U19
Atalanta U19
Red Bull Salzburg U19
Man Utd U19
Bayern Munich U19
SL Benfica Lisbon U19
Wolfsburg U19
Juventus U19
Ajax U19
AC Milan U19
Dortmund U19
Porto U19
Paris St-G U19
Real Madrid U19
Inter U19
Club Brugge U19
Atletico Madrid U19
Sporting CP U19
Liverpool U19
Man City U19
Shakhtar U19
Besiktas JK U19
Sheriff Tiraspol U19
Carlisle
Huracan
Kasimpasa
Sochi
Sarmiento de Junin
Penafiel
Rio Ave
Covilha
Burnley
Man Utd U21
NFC Volos
Lamia
Asteras Tripolis
Panaitolikos
Zulte-Waregem
BG Pathumthani United
Istiqlol
Tranmere
Al-Hilal
OFI
Ionikos
Lokomotiva
Atromitos
FC Koln
Viktoria Koln
Wehen Wiesbaden
HNK Gorica
Ecuador
Venezuela
Chile
Bolivia
Peru
Tigre
Switzerland
Belgium
Estonia
San Marino
Andorra
England
Germany
Romania
Liechtenstein
Sweden
Spain
Lithuania
Finland
Scotland
Israel
Moldova
Latvia
Gibraltar
Slovenia
Malta
Cyprus
Portugal
Serbia
Kazakhstan
Colchester
Rotherham
Coquimbo Unido
FC Utrecht
Lecce
Parma
US Cremonese
Sassuolo
Rayo Vallecano
Napoli
Torino
Empoli
NK Istra
FC Groningen
Real Sociedad
Atalanta
Lazio
Frosinone
NK Hrvatski Dragovoljac
Inter
Venezia
Bremer SV
Newport County
AC Ajaccio
Accrington
Bolton
Rochdale
Cheltenham
Wycombe
AFC Wimbledon
Northampton
Barrow
Stevenage
Crewe
Forest Green
Cambridge Utd
Sunderland
Oxford Utd
Morecambe
Plymouth
Doncaster
Sevilla
AC Milan
West Ham
Celta Vigo
Juventus
Como
Goztepe
Antalyaspor
Atletico Madrid
Las Palmas
Basaksehir
Arsenal
Fuenlabrada
Alanyaspor
Barcelona
Sparta Rotterdam
Tenerife
Valencia
Lugo
Man City
Newcastle
Brentford
Kobe
Hiroshima
Oviedo
Valladolid
Adana Demirspor
Tottenham
Roma
Brescia
Granada
Auxerre
Reggina
Malaga
Giresunspor
Ternana
Alessandria
Almeria
Athletic Bilbao
Boavista
Malatyaspor
Fenerbahce
Burgos
Brann
Sporting Gijon
Willem II
Gil Vicente
PEC Zwolle
Kashima
Fukuoka
Shonan
Oita
Heracles
Cadiz
Liverpool
Betis
FC Twente
Quevilly Rouen
Real Madrid
Espanyol
Alaves
Alcorcon
Az Alkmaar
Spal
AC Monza
Amiens
Pau
Grenoble
Le Havre
Dunkerque
Pisa
NEC Nijmegen
Kayserispor
Sociedad B
Altay
Amorebieta
Valenciennes
Bournemouth
Brighton
Crystal Palace
Southampton
Wolves
Aston Villa
Kawasaki
Leeds
Bayern Munich
Besiktas
Ibiza Eivissa
Spezia
Perugia
Cosenza
Eibar
Heerenveen
LDU
Barcelona (Ecu)
Sporting Cristal
Nagoya
FC Minaj
Sportfreunde Lotte
Shimizu
Tokushima
Urawa
FC Tokyo
Hoffenheim
Lens
Clermont
Lorient
Angers
Mainz
Kristiansund
Elversberg
TSV Havelse
Middlesbrough
Reims
Wolfsburg
Portimonense
Lille
Nottm Forest
Belenenses
Marseille
FC 08 Villingen
Rot-Weiss Koblenz

Hertha Berlin
Famalicao
Freiburg
FC Lviv
Tromso
Livingston
Tondela
Eintracht Frankfurt
Union Berlin
Greifswalder SV 04
Leverkusen
Arminia Bielefeld
Augsburg
Bochum
Stuttgart
Huddersfield
Peterborough
Hull
Millwall
Reading
Brest
Birmingham
Paris St-G
Braga
Weiche Flensburg
Lokomotiv Leipzig
Bayreuth
Norderstedt
Wuppertaler
BFC Dynamo
Lyon
SSV Ulm
Babelsberg
Estoril Praia
Blackpool
Dortmund
Moreirense
Swansea
Barnsley
RB Leipzig
Sporting Lisbon
Nantes
Yokohama FM
KS Teuta Durres
Pacos Ferreira
Shakhter Karagandy
Anorthosis
Vitesse Arnhem
Trabzonspor
Paola Hibernians FC
HB Torshavn
FK Jablonec
Omonia
Slavia Prague
Dinamo Zagreb
Benfica
PAOK
Monaco
Rangers
Shakhtar
Brazil Olympic
Spain Olympic
Sendai
Deportivo Pereira
Zorya
Verl
Millonarios
Banfield
Jaguares de Cordoba
Hallescher FC
Viktoria Berlin
Luzern
FK Desna Chernihiv
Veres Rivne
Cuiaba
Boca Juniors
Rukh Vynnyky
Red Bull Salzburg
Motherwell
Sturm Graz
Standard
Dundee Utd
Brusque FC
FC Ufa
St Mirren
St Johnstone
Hearts
Dundee
FSV Zwickau
Kaiserslautern
VFL Osnabruck
Waldhof Mannheim
Dnipro-1
Dortmund II
Chernomorets Odesa
Quindio
Nautico PE
Alianza Petrolera
Admira Wacker
Slavia Mozyr
Lausanne
FC Magdeburg
Metalist 1925
G-Osaka
ABC RN
Energetik - BGU Minsk
Genk
Rigas Futbola Skola
A.E.L.
KF Shkupi
Prishtina
Linfield
KF Drita
Partizan Belgrade
Bohemians
FC Astana
F91 Dudelange
NK Maribor
Osijek
Molde
KF Laci
Partizani Tirana
FC Ararat Yerevan
Baltija Panevezys
Gzira United FC
FK Velez Mostar
FK Sutjeska
Shakhter Soligorsk
FK Riga
FK Sumqayit
Lokomotiv Plovdiv
Cukaricki
Slovacko
Valerenga
FK Suduva
Arda
Larne
FK Spyris Kaunas
Breidablik
Domzale
KuPS
Apollon Limassol
Dinamo Tbilisi
CS Petrocub
Dinamo Batumi
Hafnarfjordur
CSKA Sofia
Hajduk Split
Olimpija
Valur
Ujpest
Hibernian
Dundalk
Qarabag Fk
Zilina
FC Ashdod
FC Milsami-Ursidos
Spartak Trnava
Torpedo BelAZ
Aberdeen
Liepajas Metalurgs
Tobol Kostanay
Kesla
Birkirkara
Plzen
Ferencvaros
VMFD Zalgiris
Qingdao Huanghai FC
HJK Helsinki
Tallinna FC Flora
Zaglebie Lubin
FC Olimpiyets NN
Puebla
Ind Medellin
ACS Sepsi OSK
AIK
Vejle
Dinamo Bucharest
Orlando City
Envigado
Philadelphia
New York Red Bulls
Kansas City
Grasshoppers Zurich
FC Cincinnati
Houston Dynamo
Holstein Kiel
OB
FC Zurich
Shanghai Shenhua
Rakow Czestochowa
Silkeborg
FK Krasnodar
Servette
Wolfsberger AC
Isloch
Warta Poznan
Gaz Metan Medias
Viborg
Union St Gilloise
Gornik Zabrze
Universitatea Craiova
Gent
Santiago Wanderers
Santa Fe
River Plate Asuncion
Universidad de Chile
Portland Timbers
LA Galaxy
4 de Julho
AaB
Aalesunds
AC Horsens
Academica Clinceni
Adelaide United
AEK Athens
Afghanistan
AGF
Ajax
Akhmat Grozny
Al Ahli
Al Ahly Benghazi
Al Ain
Al Nasr FC Riyadh
Al Sharjah
AL Shorta Baghdad
Albania
America de Cali S.A
America MG
Anderlecht
Ankaragucu
Antofagasta
APOEL
Aragua FC
Ararat Armenia
Arcahaie FC
Argentina
Arka Gdynia
Armenia
Arouca
Arsenal de Sarandi
Arsenal Tula
ASC Diaraf
Astra Giurgiu
Atlanta Utd
Atlas
Atletico Bucaramanga
Atletico Huila
Atletico Palmaflor Vinto
Aucas
Austin FC
Austria
Austria Klagenfurt
Austria Vienna
Avai
Aves
Azerbaijan
B36 Torshavn
Bahrain
Bala Town
Bangladesh
Barry Town Utd
BATE Borisov
Bayern Munich II
Beitar Jerusalem
Belarus
Belshina Bobruisk
Benevento
Binacional
Blackburn
Boa
Boavista RJ
Bodo Glimt
Bologna
Borac Banja Luka
Bordeaux
Bosnia
Botosani
Boulogne
Boyaca Chico
Boyaca Patriotas
Bragantino SP
Brasil de Pelotas
Brasiliense
Braunschweig
Brazil
Bristol City
Brondby
Bursaspor
C-Osaka
CA Rentistas
Cagliari
Cambodia
Canet Roussillon FC
Cardiff
Carl Zeiss Jena
Carlos Mannucci
CD Marathon
CD Nacional Funchal
CD Olimpia
CDA Navalcarnero
Celtic
Centro Atletico Fenix
Cercle Brugge
CF America
CFR Cluj
Chambly Oise
Charleroi
Charleroi-Marchienne
Chateaubriant
Chateauroux
Chelsea
Chemnitzer
Chicago Fire
Chievo
Chindia Targoviste
Chinese Taipei
Chongqing Lifan
Cianorte PR
Cittadella
Club Atletico Pantoja
Club Brugge
Cobresal
Coimbra
Coleraine
Colombia
Colorado
Columbus
Confianca
Connahs Quay
Coritiba
Coventry
Cracovia Krakow
Croatia
Crotone
Crvena Zvezda
CS Mioveni
CS Petange
CSKA Moscow
CSMS Iasi
Cucuta Deportivo
Curico Unido
DC Utd
Degerfors
Den Bosch
Denizlispor
Denmark
Deportes Melipilla
Deportivo Cali
Deportivo La Guaira
Deportivo Lara
Deportivo Pasto
Deportivo Tachira
Derby
Derry City
Dijon
Dinamo Brest
Dinamo Minsk
Dinamo Moscow
Dinamo Zagreb U19
Djurgardens
Dunajska Streda
Dynamo Dresden
Dynamo Kiev
EC Vitoria Salvador
Elche
Elfsborg
Entella
Enyimba
Erzgebirge
Erzurum BB
Esbjerg
ESTAC Troyes
Esteghlal FC
Eupen
Europa FC
Everton
Extremadura UD
Falkenbergs
Farense
Faroe Islands
Fatih Karagumruk Istanbul
FC Basel
FC Cartagena
FC Copenhagen
FC Dallas
Fc Differdange 03
FC Dinamo Auto
FC Goa
FC Gomel
FC Heidenheim
FC Inter
FC Juarez
FC Khimki
FC Lokomotivi Tbilisi
FC Minsk
FC Noah
FC Nordsjaelland
FC Ordabasy
FC Orenburg
FC Ruh Brest
FC Saburtalo Tbilisi
FC Santa Coloma
FC Shirak
FC Smolevichi-STI
FC Smorgon
FC U Craiova 1948
FC Vaduz
FC Volendam
FC Voluntari
Fci Tallinn
FCSB
Feyenoord
Figueirense
Fiorentina
FK Backa Topola
FK Buducnost Podgorica
FK Iskra Danilovgrad
FK Kaisar
FK Kukesi
FK Mariupol
FK Renova
FK Sileks
FK Sputnik
FK Tambov
FK Ventspils
FK Zeta Golubovci
Floriana
Fola Esch
Fortuna Sittard
France
Fulham
Galatasaray
General Diaz
Genoa
Getafe
GFA Rimully Vallieres
Girona
Glentoran
Go Ahead Eagles
Gorodeya
Greece
Guadalajara
Guam
Guangzhou FC
Guayaquil City
Guimaraes
Guingamp
Gwangju FC
Hacken
Hamburger SV
Hamilton
Hannover
Hansa Rostock
Hapoel Beer Sheva
Hartberg
Hatayspor
Haugesund
Hermannstadt
Hobro
Hong Kong
Honka
Honved
Huachipato
Huesca
Hungary
HUSA Agadir
Iceland
Ilves
India
Indonesia
Ingolstadt
Inhulets Petrove
Inter Club Escaldes
Inter Miami CF
Internacional
Iran
Italy
Jagiellonia Bialystock
Jahn Regensburg
Japan
Jiangsu Suning
Jordan
Jorge Wilstermann
Juazeirense BA
Juve Stabia
Juventude
Kabylie
Kairat Almaty
Kaizer Chiefs
Karlsruhe
Kashiwa
Kaya
KF Gjilani
KF Tirana
Kfco Beerschot Wilrijk
Kilmarnock
Kitchee SC
Klaksvikar Itrottarfelag
Kolos Kovalyovka
Korona Kielce
Kortrijk
Kosovo
KR Reykjavik
Kryliya Sovetov
Kuwait
KV Oostende
Kyrgyzstan
La Equidad
LA Fiorita
Lanus
Larissa
LASK Linz
LD Alajuelense
Le Puy
Lech Poznan
Lechia Gdansk
Leganes
Legia Warsaw
Leicester
Leon
Levante
Lillestrom
Lincoln Red Imps
Liverpool Montevideo
Livorno
LKS Lodz
Lokomotiv
Los Angeles FC
Lubeck
Ludogorets
Lugano
Luton
Lyngby
Lyon U19
Macara
Maccabi Haifa
Maccabi Tel Aviv
Malaysia
Mallorca
Mamelodi Sundowns
Man Utd
Maritimo
Mattersburg
MC Alger
Metropolitanos
Metz
Midtjylland
Mineros Guayana
Minnesota Utd
Mjallby
Mjondalen
MOL Vidi
Mongolia
Montenegro
Monterrey
Montpellier
Mura
Myanmar
NAC Breda
Nacional (Uru)
Nacional Potosi
Namungo FC
Nancy
Napsa Stars
Nashville SC
Necaxa
Neftchi Baku
Neman Grodno
Nepal
Netherlands
Neuchatel Xamax
New England
New York City
Nice
Nimes
Niort
NK Celje
Nkana
Nomme Kalju
North Korea
North Macedonia
Northern Ireland
Norway
Norwich
NSI Runavik
Nublense
Numancia
Odds BK
Oeste
OHiggins
Olimpik Donetsk
Olmaliq
Olympiakos
Oman
Once Caldas
Osasuna
Ostersunds FK
Oud-Heverlee Leuven
Pachuca
Paderborn
Padideh
Paide Linnameeskond
Pakhtakor
Palestine
Palestino
Panathinaikos
Panionios
Paraguay
Parana
Paris FC
PAS Giannina
Penarol
Persepolis
Pescara
Philippines
Piast Gliwice
Plaza Colonia
Podbeskidzie B-B
Pogon Szczecin
Ponferradina
Pordenone
Port FC
Porto
Preston
Preussen Munster
Progres Niedercorn
PSV
Puerto Cabello
Pumas UNAM
Puskas Akademia
Qatar
QPR
Queretaro
Racing Santander
Raja Casablanca
Randers
Rapid Bucharest
Rapid Vienna
Ratchaburi
Real Esteli FC
Real Salt Lake
Red Star
Reggiana
Remo
Rennes
Republic of Ireland
Republic of Maldives
Rijeka
Rionegro
Riteriai
River Plate
River Plate (Uru)
Rizespor
RKC Waalwijk
Rodez
Rosenborg
Ross Co
Rostov
Rot-Weiss Essen
Rotor Volgograd
Royal Mouscron-peruwelz
RSB Berkane
Rubin Kazan
Ruzomberok
Sabadell
Salernitana
Salitas FC
Sampdoria
San Jose Earthquakes
Sandefjord
Santa Clara
Sao Bento
Sao Caetano
Sapporo
Sarajevo
Sarpsborg
Saudi Arabia
Saumur
Schalke 04
SCR Altach
Seattle Sounders
Sedan
Setubal
Sfintul Gheorghe
SG Sonnenhof
Shamrock Rovers
Shanghai East Asia
Sheff Utd
Sheriff Tiraspol
Shkendija
Singapore
Sint Truiden
Sion
Sirens FC
Sirius
Sivasspor
Slask Wroclaw
Slavia Sofia
Slovakia
Slovan Bratislava
Slovan Liberec
Slutsk
Sochaux
SonderjyskE
SP Tre Fiori
SP Tre Penne
Sparta Prague
Spartak Moscow
Sport Huancayo
Sport Recife
Sportivo Luqueno
Sportivo San Lorenzo
Sri Lanka
St Etienne
St Gallen
St Pauli
St Polten
St. Joseph's FC
Stabaek
Stal Mielec
Start
Stoke
Strasbourg
Stromsgodset
SV Darmstadt
SV Meppen
SV Ried
SV Sandhausen
Syria
Tajikistan
Tampines Rovers
Teungueth FC
Thailand
The New Saints
Thun
Tijuana
Toluca
Tosu
Toulouse
Tractor Sazi FC
Trapani
Tupynambas FC
Turkmenistan
UAE
Uberlandia MG
UD Logrones
Udinese
UE Engordany
Uerdingen
Union Espanola
Union La Calera
Unterhaching
Ural
Uruguay
UTA Arad
UTC Cajamarca
Uzbekistan
Valletta
Valmieras FK
Varbergs BoIS
Viettel FC
Farul Constanta
Vikingur Reykjavik
Vila Nova
Vita Club
Vitebsk
Vojvodina
Volta Redonda
Waasland-Beveren
Wales
Watford
Werder Bremen
West Brom
Western United
Wisla Krakow
Wisla Plock
Xanthi
Yellow-Red Mechelen
Yemen
Yokohama FC
Young Boys
Zaragoza
Zeljeznicar
Zenit St Petersburg
Zrinjski
Nieciecza
Radomiak Radom
Gornik Leczna
Seraing Utd
Freiburg II
Vllaznia Shkoder
Japan Olympic
Mexico Olympic
Vizela
Verona
Catanzaro
Mirandes
Oldham
Wigan
Shrewsbury
Gillingham
Slaven Belupo
Sibenik
Mexico
El Salvador
Honduras
USA
Swindon
Walsall
Leyton Orient
Ipswich
Bradford
Young Boys U19
OSC Lille U19
Dynamo Kyiv U19
Barcelona U19
Sevilla U19
Chelsea U19
Villarreal U19
Bristol Rovers
Boluspor
Samsunspor
Adanaspor
Tarsus Idman Yurdu
Bucaspor
Bergama Belediyespor
Erzincanspor
Kocaelispor
Corum Belediyespor
Hekimoglu Trabzon
Serik Belediyespor
Etimesgut Belediyespor
Keciorengucu
Kirsehir Belediyespor
Ankara Demirspor
Karacabey Belediyespor AS
Sariyer G.K.
Afjet Afyonspor
Istanbulspor
Usakspor
Ankaraspor
Menemen Belediyespor
Balikesirspor
Turgutluspor
Eskisehirspor
Bandirmaspor
Westlandia
Harkemase Boys
Ado '20
De Treffers
Achilles Veen
Staphorst
Osmaniyespor 2011
Umraniyespor
Tuzlaspor
Altinordu
Sakaryaspor
MTK Budapest U19
Hajduk Split U19
MSK Zilina U19
Angers U19
Maccabi Haifa U19
Yate Town FC
FC Halifax Town
Chesterfield
Boreham Wood
York City
Grimsby
Altrincham
Gambia
Burkina Faso
AS Cavaly
Bani Yas
ENPPI
CD Trasandino
Deportes Limache
Mumbai City FC
Quilmes
```

List of values I want to know if any of them are not in the previous list:

```
Philadelphia
Nacional (Par)
Argentinos Juniors
Vancouver Whitecaps
Energetik - BGU Minsk
Elfsborg
Sirius
Kalmar FF
Malmo FF
El Gounah
Pharco FC
Patronato
Future FC
Universidad de Chile
Club Sportivo Ameliano
Tolima
Atl Tucuman
Operario PR
Sampaio Correa FC
Tacuary
Shandong Luneng
Guangzhou City
Ghazl El Mahallah
Al Mokawloon
Zamalek
Rosario Central
New York City
Guarani (Par)
Arsenal De Sarandi
New England

Varbergs BoIS
IFK Goteborg
Varnamo
Helsingborgs
Eastern Company SC
Al Ittihad (EGY)
CA Independiente
El Geish
CD General Velasquez
Guairena
Atletico Nacional Medellin
Godoy Cruz
Chapecoense
CSA
Sol de America (Par)
Henan
Dalian Yifang
Ismaily
National Bank
Ceramica Cleopatra
Quilmes
```

Actual Result:

```
Nacional (Par)

Al Ittihad (EGY)
Sol de America (Par)
```

Expected Result:

```
Arsenal De Sarandi
```

How should I proceed in this case that has more detail in the data to be worked on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=FILTER(D1:D, REGEXMATCH(D1:D, "^("&REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A:A),"([().])","\\$1")&")$")=FALSE)
```

- In the `List of saved values`, there are special characters `().` which have to be escaped
- In your `REGEXMATCH` expression, you have to specify exact match `^(...)$`